# what is sparse solution?

Tags: sparse

[image]

This graph is about panelty least square method, and it is said that once a parameter hits zero, it remains zero for larger garmma, and this results in a sparse solution. I am wondering what it means to say that "this results in a sparse solution".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As gamma increases, more variables' coefficients go to 0. Once a variable has a 0 coefficient, it has no impact on the model anymore. So, as gamma increases, the model uses fewer and fewer variables. This is what we mean by a sparse solution - it only uses a few variables in the dataset.

Other methods may produce a solution where many variables have small, but non-zero coefficients. These models are not sparse, since you still need all the variables to produce the solution. A sparse solution is generally preferred since you can explain your model in terms of just a few variables.

Comment: May I also ask what it means to "impose sparsity", does this just mean to reduce the explanatory variables through factor analysis or PCA for example?

Comment: @luca590 I'd say a model imposes sparsity through its regularization term. As gamma increases in the OP's plot, more coefficients are driven to 0, imposing sparsity.